# What does the word 'broke' mean in "country Is 'Broke' With state subsidies...."

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

Does "broke" here mean "without money"?

> **Brazil's President Says Country Is 'Broke'**
>
> With state subsidies to fight poverty now ended, Brazil's far-right President Jair Bolsonaro on Tuesday said his country is "broke" and he is unable to do anything about it, attributing the crisis to "the press-fueled" coronavirus.

Source:  [International Business Times](https://www.ibtimes.com/brazils-president-says-country-broke-3115320)

Comment: It means *having completely run out of money*. (Lexico)

Comment: If he had said _broken_ it would mean something else. Does that help resolve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article goes on explaining that.

> Bolsonaro attributes **the country's economic collapse** to lockdown measures pushed by state governors to combat the coronavirus pandemic.

His statement that the country *went broke* (or *is broke* = **without money**), which might be a bit exaggerated, means the government can't simultaneously tackle the pandemic and bring in the promised tax reforms. In his opinion, **there is not enough money** to handle both (or that the pandemic took all the resources, a good part of which might have been allocated towards the new tax regulations).

Comment: Right, that's the answer. Do you know why I wrote the intended meaning in a 'comment'?

Comment: @Void, no, you could have posted it as an answer...

Comment: I had [posted it as an answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/271278/106592) (only 10k users can see), but I edited it and wrote *XXXXXXXX Google it XXXXXXX* instead. Should I explain it further?

Comment: It's not just exaggerated, it's also non-literal.  A country like Brazil can't be "without money" because the government has the ability to just print more if they want.  However, drastically increasing the money supply can have very negative effects, which the President wants to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

Your guess is already correct.

However, depending on the subculture (where `broke` is preferred over `bankrupt` anyways), the substitution `poor af` may be the best fit. :)